# API to write on a mount using vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Writing a file's content on a vault mount is quite easy. I am doing this:

```
vault write kv key=@C:\Users\abc\Desktop\abc.txt value=C:\Users\abc\Desktop\abc.txt
```

Reading this gives key as the content of abc.txt and value as full path of abc.txt

However, doing so using HTTP API is not getting through with me.

The documentation says, send a POST request with the value to write as JSON Body.

Now, I have tried below as the payload but it simply writes with '@' on vault instead of the content.

```
{
  "key": "@C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\abc.txt",
  "value": "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\abc.txt"

}
```

How to achieve the write part where content of a file is written on vault mount path.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work, how can an API call read a file from your local disk? Does the documentation really say you can do that?

Comment: No. It does not say that. I am wondering how to send content of a file to vault mount using API

Comment: You'd have to open the file yourself in code and put the contents in the value field of your json POST. Probably should use some form of encoding to make sure you are sending valid json.